# A query return the exact result but on local cache there are unexpected items

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework-6

I'm using vb.net 2017 and Entity Framework 6 with sql server 2008r2.
I have 2 tables in database :

Studnets: (ID , Name )

Status : (ID , Year , Student_ID , Active )

The table status has the status of students in a specific year. A student may have 0 or 1 status on a year . ( If a student has not a status on a year , the last status from previous years ( if exists ) is used as a status for it this year)

Now I want to have a query that load on local cache only the students that are active on a specific year.

This is my query :

```
Dim queryv As IEnumerable(Of students)
            queryv = (From t1 In context.students order by t.Name select t)
            queryv = (From t1 In queryv
                      Let p = t1.status.Where(Function(t2) 
t2.year<=year1).OrderBy(Function(t3) t3.year).LastOrDefault
                      Where Not IsNothing(p) AndAlso p.active = True
                      Select t1)
queryv.Tolist
```

On Database there are 2 students , one of them has an Active status this year , the other has a non-active status.
The problem is that after i excute that query , i have 2 instructions , just for testing :

```
Messagebox.show(queryv.count)

MessageBox.show(context.studnets.local.Count)
```

The results are :

1 (for queryv)

2 (for local cache )

On Local cache both students exists.
Why is this result ?

Thank you !

Comment: Change `IEnumerable(Of students)` to `IQueryable(Of students)` and you'll see the difference.

Comment: @IvanStoev After the change , i get an error : LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Program1.status LastOrDefault[status](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Program1.status])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.'

Comment: Well, that's the difference :) Seriously, the second part of the original query was executing in memory, that's why the local cache has been populated. Now the whole query is translated to SQL, but you are using unsupported construct. Use `OrderByDescending` + `FirstOrDefault` instead.

Comment: @IvanStoev I've used OrderByDescending + FirstorDefault , and now i have another error : 'LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean IsNothing(System.Object)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.'

Comment: Well, that simply means VB `IsNothing` function is another non translatable method. I'm not quite familiar with VB, but I guess you should use the standard `Is Nothing` operator instead, e.g. something like `Not p Is Nothing`